# 2005 Hyundai Sonata v6 won’t start, has compression, Fire, and crank

Tags: starting, hyundai, sonata

My car has been running fine and I stopped to get gas, put $40 in and it wouldn’t start back up. I did have the purge valve replaced after this because after getting gas every time it would be hard to start. Once it started, I could move the car 5 ft, turn it off and it would fire up every time. It only did this when I get gas and looked it up that, that was a common issue with these cars. Anyway we ran a code test on it and it didn’t show any codes, no stored codes, no pending codes, nothing. I don’t want to spend a lot of money trying things because I just don’t have a lot of money to be in the hole and still have a car that won’t start. I have been told that it could be the timing by a few peopl and then others say it’s not the timing. I need help badly. Any ideas????

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It sounds likely to be a fuel issue. You need to check the fuel pressure at the rail and see what it says. I'm wondering if at this point it may be a fuel pump.

Comment: One simple thing you can do to help narrow down the problem is to spray some starter fluid into the throttle body. If your engine starts up after that you are almost certainly dealing with a fuel delivery problem

Comment: We have done that and it’s not starting. It doesn’t do any different than when we don’t do it. It sounds exactly the same and still does nothing.

Comment: How do you know that it's getting spark?

Comment: We pulled a plug to check it. The person who did it got zapped.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was going on with the car I have the same issue